# NVRM: Xid: 70, GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, hybrid-graphics, 16.10

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 on a Lenovo Z510 with gt 740m. Using any NVidia driver, when I try to wake up from suspend the screen is black and an error is displayed:

```
[ 1046.061495] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
[ 1047.081663] [drm:hsw_write_dcomp [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to write to D_COMP
[ 1047.369023] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:07:00): 70, GPU has fallen off the bus.
[ 1046.061495] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
[ 1046.061495] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
```

When I was on Ubuntu 16.04, the same problem occurred, but the screen was completely black, without the error.

Answer (score 1):

Due to acpi BIOS incompatibilities, the Z510 needs an additional kernel commandline parameter `acpi_osi="!Windows 2013"` for suspend/resume to work.

See: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/142

The `drm:wait_panel_status` has been appearing since kernel 4.8 but so far I haven't notice any negative effects.

Comment: Where this parameter should be added ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Xid errors list](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/) (check [PDF](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/XID_Errors.pdf)), the error 70 (*CE3: Unknown Error*) is related to driver or hardware issue. Try upgrading your driver to the latest version.

For different error such as 79, check: [NVRM: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus](https://askubuntu.com/q/974375/78223).