# ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed; NVRM: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 17.10, acpi

I've got two problems:

1. My laptop does not wake up when it is suspended and it shows these messages in a black screen:

   ```
   [349.417870] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace
   lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)             
   [349.417881] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN04._OFF,         AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)   
   [349.417963] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace
   lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)             
   [349.417970] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN03._OFF,         AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)  
   [349.418041] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace
   lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)             
   [349.418047] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN02._OFF,        AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)   
   [349.418114] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace
   lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)             
   [349.418121] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN01._OFF,         AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)   
   [350.802831] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECWT] Namespace
   lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psargs-364)                   
   [350.802934] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_TZ.FN00._OFF,        AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550) 
   [350.925661] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.OFSV] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)  
   [350.925780] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \S_B.PCI0.PGOF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)   
   [350.925880] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \S_B.PCI0.PEG0.PG00._OFF, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)  
   [350.928692] NVRM: Xid (PCI:000:04:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.
   ```
2. I've tried to disable the suspend mode when I close the lid, modifying the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and the `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file but none of those worked.

What should I do?

Comment: I have managed to solve the second problem, but the first still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suspend fails, GPU has fallen off the bus (Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857453/suspend-fails-gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-nvidia)

Answer (score 1):

As per [Xid errors list](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/), error 79 (*GPU has fallen off the bus*) can be related to variety of things such as driver or hardware issue, system memory corruption, bus error or thermal issue (overheating).

Run *NVIDIA X Server Settings* app (which comes with the drivers) and check the temperature, graphic clock, performance levels and GPU utilization levels.

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180342/55075) (based on this original [thread](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/957456/geforce-drivers/gtx-1080-throwing-bad-tlp-pcie-bus-errors/post/4969345/#4969345)), suggests to disable PCI-E ASPM ([Active State Power Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_State_Power_Management)) by changing boot params to `pcie_aspm=off` (it [forcibly disables PCIe ASPM](https://serverfault.com/q/226319/130437)).

Related bug report: [GPU has fallen off the bus](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048032/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus/).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution: changing the driver of my graphic card, instead of using NVIDIA binary driver, use the X.Org X server [NVIDIA driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9odIN.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that switching to Intel graphics using the Nvidia tool, without uninstalling the Nvidia proprietary drivers, also makes resume from suspend work. (This is option is only available if you have a card that supports Nvidia's Optimus technology).

Also, the error shown on my screen was slightly different; I'm listing it here in case it helps someone with their online search:

```
[44.436337] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 32, Channel ID 00000000 intr 80040000
```

Here is a screenshot of the Nvidia tool with Intel graphics selected:

[image]

Comment: [Xid Error 32](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html#topic_4) relates to _Invalid or corrupted push buffer stream_. _This event is logged when a fault is reported by the DMA controller which manages the communication stream between the NVIDIA driver and the GPU over the PCI-E bus. These failures primarily involve quality issues on PCI, and are generally not caused by user application actions._